# Angular Material Problem in version 8.2.14

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

**Edit (08/20/2020 14:12h)**:

I get more details due to HTML parse:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-card-title' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-card-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    [ERROR ->]<mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
"): ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.html@11:4
'mat-card-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-card-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
```

---

**UPDATED**:

I fix most of the problem. Now the case is about **@angular/cdk** packages:

```
node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/padding.d.ts:36:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

36     set indent(indent: number | string);
           ~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/toggle.d.ts:17:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

17     get recursive(): boolean;
           ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/toggle.d.ts:18:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

18     set recursive(value: boolean);
           ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/tree.d.ts:37:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

37     get dataSource(): DataSource<T> | Observable<T[]> | T[];
           ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/tree.d.ts:38:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

38     set dataSource(dataSource: DataSource<T> | Observable<T[]> | T[]);
           ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/tree.d.ts:103:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

103     get data(): T;
            ~~~~
node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/tree.d.ts:104:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

104     set data(value: T);
            ~~~~
node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/tree.d.ts:106:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

106     get isExpanded(): boolean;
            ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/tree.d.ts:107:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

107     get level(): number;
```

**CMD Console**

```
npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/cdk@10.1.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/cdk@10.1.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@8.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@8.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Is there any solution for that? Thanks! :)

---

Seeing these questions about this subject: [@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594311/angular-material-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module), [How to import Angular Material in project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166844/how-to-import-angular-material-in-project), and implementing the module as it follows, the compiler gave me an error.

**angular-material.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {
  MatCardModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatMenuModule,
   MatButtonModule,
   MatToolbarModule,
   MatIconModule,
   MatBadgeModule,
   MatSidenavModule,
   MatListModule,
   MatGridListModule,
   MatFormFieldModule,
   MatInputModule,
   MatSelectModule,
   MatRadioModule,
   MatDatepickerModule,
   MatNativeDateModule,
   MatChipsModule,
   MatTooltipModule,
   MatTableModule,
   MatPaginatorModule,
   MatProgressSpinnerModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
    MatCardModule, 
    MatDialogModule, 
    MatMenuModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
      CommonModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatSidenavModule,
      MatBadgeModule,
      MatListModule,
      MatGridListModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatSelectModule,
      MatRadioModule,
      MatDatepickerModule,
      MatNativeDateModule,
      MatChipsModule,
      MatTooltipModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatPaginatorModule
   ],
   exports: [
    MatCardModule, 
    MatDialogModule, 
    MatMenuModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatSidenavModule,
      MatBadgeModule,
      MatListModule,
      MatGridListModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatSelectModule,
      MatRadioModule,
      MatDatepickerModule,
      MatChipsModule,
      MatTooltipModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatPaginatorModule
   ],
   providers: [
      MatDatepickerModule,
   ]
})

export class AngularMaterialModule { }
```

Lately, in **package.json** I added like this to put an older version compatible with node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "chokidar": "^3.4.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

Finally, in **app.module.ts** I added the dependency file:

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from './angular-material.module';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import {BasicAuthHtppInterceptorService} from './service/basic-auth-interceptor.service';
```

My app structure is similar to this:

[image: Angular App Structure]

What should I do in order to display the HTML tags on this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your package.json, you're using Angular 8.3, and you have @angular/cdk@10.1.3. You can downgrade your angular/cdk version by using

```
npm i @angular/cdk@8.2.1
```

or you can upgrade your Angular version to v9 by running:

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

That will update your local angular version to 9. Then, just to sync material, run: `ng update @angular/material`

Comment: I see, thanks for your curiousity, but I need to still in the version 8.2.14, and all the material running though the HTML. For instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479557/how-do-you-deal-with-div-with-mat-card-header-text-in-an-material2-card/47439591

Comment: yes for that maintain all your version to 8.2 or below that. it will work.